# Discord.js V12 Sending an embed to a channel in a different guild

Tags: node.js, discord.js

HI i was making a command where it sends an embed to a channel with an id however the command works normally when used in the guild where it has that channel but when the command is used in a different guild it throws error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined" is there any way to fix this? i want the command to be usable in other guilds as well

```js
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === "746423099871985755")
                
                const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#FFFF33')
                .setTitle(message.member.user.tag)
                .setAuthor(`Order ID: ${ticketID}`)
                .setDescription(order)
                .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(`From ${message.guild.name} (${message.guild.id})`);
            
                channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

Comment: The error you get is absolutely understandable, because on other guilds there is no channel with exact that ID. Every channel has a different ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Message#guild` is the current guild. So if you want to send the message into a channel from another guild you need to search for that guild in your cache from your client. You can do this by writing:

```
const guild = message.client.guilds.cache.get("/* Your guild id */");
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("/* Your channel id */");
```

You can also do it a bit compacter:

```
const channel = message.client.guilds.cache.get("/* Your guild id */").channels.cache.get("/* Your channel id */");
```

If you want to search with channel-names:

```
const channel = message.client.guilds.cache.get("/* Your guild id */").channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "/* Channel name */");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every single channel on Discord has a different ID, you can't get two different channel objects with one ID. What you can do instead is use a channel's name (the channel will have to have the same name in both servers), or you can hard code both channels manually.

e.g.

```js
// using names
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "channel-name");

// hardcoding IDs
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === "ID1" || c.id === "ID2");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work `message.guild.channels.cache.get('GUILD_ID').send(embed);`